# How do I reset a PasswordChar?

Tags: c#

I want to make my PasswordChar in a text box empty when a user clicks a button (so they can confirm they wrote it right, it's easier than having to type it twice)

However, when I do:

```
password.PasswordChar = null;
```

It says

> Cannot convert null to 'char' because it is a non-nullable value type

Setting it to '' says it's an empty char, and ' ' just makes it a space. What do I do?

Comment: Your approach is wrong. The reason sites make them type it twice is that it's easy to not read carefully enough and miss a mistake. Having to type it twice the same way ensures the person doesn't accidentally confirm a mistake. Typing it twice is for a reason; taking a shortcut is going to leave lots of users frustrated because they're locked out of something, and is going to increase your support requirements. There are reasons **not** to reinvent the wheel.

Comment: It's a login thing, kind of like when you login to a windows 8 computer. That was just an analogy I made up in the original post.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

You can use:

```
password.PasswordChar = '\0';
```

`\0` refers to a [null character](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_character).

Answer (score 6):

You should be able to do this:

```
password.PasswordChar = '\0';
```

Answer (score 3):

[image]

**vb.net**

```
 txt_password.PasswordChar = String.Empty
```

**C#**

```
  txt_password.PasswordChar = string.Empty;
```

Checkbox working:

```
  Private Sub CheckBox1_CheckedChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles CheckBox1.CheckedChanged
    If CheckBox1.Checked = True Then
        txt_password.PasswordChar = String.Empty

    Else
        txt_password.PasswordChar = "*"

    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

```
password.PasswordChar = '\u0000';
```

'\u0000' means null character in Unicode and it does the same thing as '\0'

Beware that single quote is using to represent `char`.

Answer (score 0):

For the latest version of .NET Core, you can use this code to reset a **PasswordChar**

```
YourTextBoxName.PasswordChar = (char)0;
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how i solved my problem.

```
private void checkShowPassword_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (checkShowPassword.Checked)
            {
                tbPassword.PasswordChar = '\u0000';
            }
            else
            {
                tbPassword.PasswordChar = Convert.ToChar("•");
            }
        }
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**